# Formatting an <li> element within a <div>

Tags: html, css

I have two `li` elements on my page and I want them to display one above the other, but they don't. Here is my code:

```
#floating-box {
width: 65px;
height:auto;
background-color: #484848;
margin: 54px 10px 0px 623px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
text-align: justify;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #484848;
 }
.social {
position : relative;
list-style-type : none;
margin-left: 2px;
}

.social li a {
float: left;
padding: 1px 5px 5px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
display: inline;
}
```

The HTML that uses this CSS is:

```
<div id="floating-box">
<img src="likeusnow.jpg" />
<ul class="social"><!-- Facebook Like/Share Button -->
<li><a name="fb_share" type="box_count" rel="nofollow"          share_url="http://www.mysite.com"></a> 
 </li>

<li>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" rel="nofollow" class="twitter-share-button" data- url="http://www.mysite.com" data-lang="en" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
</li>

 </ul>
```

The Facebook like button either appears on top of the twitter tweet button, or to the right of it. For some reason it varies every time.

Comment: why does the link in your first `li` have no content? And is the fb `likeusnow.jpg` supposed to be a link? If it is, perhaps you should move it into that empty link in the first `li`.

Comment: Read my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Comment: @dnagirl the likeusnow.jpg is just an image saying like us. no link. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Diodeus i have read your tutorial, what is wrong with my code then?

Comment: For starters, float:left is for a horizontal menu.

Comment: I tried changing that, it made no difference

Comment: tried changing the li css to display:block too...nothing happened

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your problem?  My guess is that the elements created by the facebook link, since they are in iframes, will mess up your layout.  We will not be able to reproduce your code since we don't have those injected facebook elements.

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code [here @ csstest.com](http://cssdesk.com/) the two `li` are well displayed one above the other, just like plain `li` elements.

And **I see nothing in your css that could affect any of the styles of the** `li` **elements**.

Are there no other css style than the ones you gave us ?

What browser are you using for testing ?

Edit1:

if you do that:

```
#floating-box 
{
width: 65px;
height:auto;
background-color: #484848;
margin: 54px 10px 0px 623px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
text-align: justify;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #484848;
}
.social li
{
list-style-type : none;
}
```

applied to:

```
<div id="floating-box">
<img src="likeusnow.jpg" />
<ul class="social"><!-- Facebook Like/Share Button -->
<li>
<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" rel="nofollow" share_url="http://www.mysite.com">A</a> 
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" rel="nofollow" class="twitter-share-button" data- url="http://www.mysite.com" data-lang="en" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

I have added a A in the first html anchor, and then you'll see, A is well listed above Tweet.

Does it help ?

Comment: I can confirm that I also see this as one item above another on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Firefox. On iExplore the Twitter button just shows the text "Tweet". So frustrating! What more CSS would be relevant? Would the container CSS be able to affect its layout?

Comment: Hi, I've just had a look at the link you gave me, but the tweet text is moved over to the right. It's not perfectly displayed, one above the other...

Comment: I have deleted some styles, see the edit in my answer, tell me if it helps.